# How can I modify the values in another document in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want update reactionResult in UserSchema.
I tried to update using updateOne and populate, but I failed.
How can I use userSchema's nickname to modify the value of the reactionResult?

This is UserSchema and ReactionSchema.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
{
    nickname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    reactionResult: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Reaction",
        required: true,
    },
},
{ timestamps: true });
```

```
const ReactionSchema = new Schema({
    rank_avg: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    num_people_together_avg: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    click_pos: {
        type: { x: Number, y: Number },
        required: true,
    },
    click_speed_avg: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    foul_count_avg: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    total_games: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
});
```

Comment: can you write your query what your are trying to use?

Comment: I want to write it in this format.     



await User.updateOne({ nickname: "nickname" }).populate("reactionResult").{set: {reactionData: {
                rank_avg: 1,
                num_people_together_avg: 1,
                click_speed_avg: 1,
                foul_count_avg: 1,
                total_games: 1,
            }}};

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#setting-populated-fields here does not have any thing defined for update after populate.